# Styling nested tables in HTML email

Tags: html, css, email

I have a template for an HTML email which uses nested tables. I'm trying to achieve maximum email client support. I'm wondering about using inline styling, should I always apply this to the lowest level `td` or can I apply a style to a parent `table` or `td`?

For example, I know in a browser, both of the below will work:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" bg-color="#eeeeee" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px;">

      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing"0" width="600">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top">
            Content 1
          </td>
          <td valign="top">
            Content 1
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="20" cellspacing="0" bg-color="#eeeeee" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">

      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing"0" width="600">
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px;">
            Content 1
          </td>
          <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px;">
            Content 1
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The difference here is the inline styling. The first example avoids repetition and is easier to maintain rather than apply the inline style to multiple child `td`s. However, will some email clients apply a new style for the child `table`, `tr` or `td`?

Comment: For fonts and stuff I always do it on every td and p.  I would also add the table style into inline styles (as well as keeping the stuff like `border="0"`, etc) for maximum compatibility.  [Mailchimp have a good guide about email templates](http://templates.mailchimp.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I started with a mailchimp template but quickly realised they put most/all styling in the `<head>` and it wasn't as backwards compatible as I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lower you put the styling the safer you will be. Many email clients already add their own style. For example if they have a css line with

```
td {
   font-size:14px;
}
```

this may break the style you desire.

Comment: So will the email client default styling override inline styling I add to a parent element?

Comment: If the css-rule of the client style is more specific. But since you never know what the client might have, it's better to be safe